# How to add dynamic lists in javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript, list

Am having the data as

```
var response = '[{"id":1,"name":"Web Demo"},{"id":2,"name":"Audio Countdown"},{"id":3,"name":"The Tab Key"},{"id":4,"name":"Music Sleep Timer"}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

So how I can add the list items dynamically so in future if the list items in the backend increases they should be added directly and how can link dynamic and static elements.

Thanks

Comment: with concat? please add how the added data should look like

Comment: it should look like      Web Demo    Audio Countdown  etc...

Comment: Dynamically u wil get the data as like static ???

Comment: Am having json data which is given above suppose if in the json data is modified for 50 items how can i get the whole list as list in html page without button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use js `appendChild` to append each item in your html like this...

```js
var response = [{"id":1,"name":"Web Demo"},{"id":2,"name":"Audio Countdown"},{"id":3,"name":"The Tab Key"},{"id":4,"name":"Music Sleep Timer"}] ;

for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) 
{ 
 var node = document.createElement("LI");  // Create a <li> node
 var textnode = document.createTextNode(response[i].name); // Create a text node
 node.appendChild(textnode); 
 document.getElementById("items").appendChild(node); ///append Item
}
```

```html
<div id="items"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks and I have a little question how can I link that <div id="items> and this exact javascript code.

Comment: you can use `document.getElementById("ID OF YOUR ELEMENT").` to link your element, you just need id of your element in which you want to append your items..

Comment: @roy why unaccepted my answer after accepting ?? is something wrong ??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your lists according the the changes in the backend, you should periodically test for that via ajax. You can use `setInterval` and 
`XMLHttpRequest` for these purposes.

When the new data arrives, you should erase your existing list and add new elements to represent the arrived data dynamically.

```
setInterval(function(){

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

     populateList(xhttp.responseText);   //This is your function to create the list

    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.mybackend.com/list", true);
  xhttp.send();

})
```

And you can use `document.createElement` function to create a series of elements to represent your data.

```
function populateList(data) {

   var obj = var obj = JSON.parse(response);

   document.getElementById('myUl').remove();    //Delete the existing list

   var myUi = document.createElement('ul');    //Add new list

   obj.forEach(item) {

       var listItem = document.createElement('li');
       myUi.appendChild(li);

       //Then add li details here
   } 

}
```

This is just rough code. Your can youse Jquery to get this done very shorter than this. You can even use a JS framework like Angular to automate most of these tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing dynamic data as like static data, use concat

```
response.concat(dynamicdata);
```