# Dynamically add item in dropdown using PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, dropdown

I have created a simple dropdown using the code below.

```html
<div class="row">
  <h2>Select Sample #1</h2>
  <select class="selectpicker" id="select1">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now need to create the dropdown in a way that I can enter new items to the dropdown so that it will be enabled to select the value and visible next time also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add dynamic lists in javascript not jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155230/how-to-add-dynamic-lists-in-javascript-not-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="select1">
    <?php foreach ($options as $optionValue => $optionName) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $optionValue ?>"> <?= $optionName ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

If you want to add items to select in browser, you must do it with js because php is back end language.

Comment: yes.. My question is that how to add item using js.

Answer (score 0):

it is so simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$txts = ["Mustard","Ketchup","Relish"]; // put you dynamic array
?>
<select class="selectpicker" id="select1">
    <?php foreach ($txts as $txt) { ?>   // add Foreachloop for display object
        <option value="<?= $txt ?>"> <?= $txt ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

if you need to add item than go for `javascript`