# How to use JavaScript with html to display values on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html

Been trying to learn html and I'm finally tackling JavaScript. I've somewhat started but I'm lost on what to do.
What I want to do is be able to update my site after the user has pressed a checkerbox and also be able to remove said value if the user unchecks the box.

To make it easier to understand I've got a pic of the site:
[image]

And what I want it to do is this. Basically, you click a box and the name of the music and it's price get put into the right side of the site and opposite when you uncheck:
[image]

Here's the code that is related to the question:

```js
function changeContent(boxElement, divToChange, innerDiv) {
    var i = boxElement.value.indexOf("|");

    var cleaned = boxElement.value.indexOf(0, i);

    var price = boxElement.value.substring(0, i);

    s = document.getElementById(divToChange).innerHTML;
    s += "<div class =" + innerDiv + ">" + cleaned + "</div>";
    document.getElementById(divToChange).innerHTML = s;
}
```

```html
<div class="chosenSongs">
                <label>Du har följande skivor:</label>
                <p class = "selectedSongs">Här kommer valda låtar synas</p>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "Polisen"></div>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "Valhalla"></div>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "Raggare på stureplan"></div>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "Monster"></div>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "Instruktionsboken"></div>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "Komplicerad"></div>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "Starkare"></div>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "wake Me Up"></div>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "Hey Brother"></div>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "You Make Me"></div>
                <div class="oneSong" value = "Levels"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="price">
                <label>Pris:</label>
            </div>
            
            <fieldset class="checkbox">
                <div class="title">Ringnes-Ronny</div>
                <div class="boxContainer">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value = "Ringnes-Ronny: Polisen|59"
                        onclick = "changeContent(this, 'chosenSongs', 'oneSong')">Polisen<span class="time">59 SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox">Valhalla<span class="time">39 SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox">Raggare på stureplan<span class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox">Monster<span class="time">39 SEK</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="title">Miss Li</div>
                <div class="boxContainer">
                    <label><input type="checkbox">Instruktionsboken<span class="time">39 SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox">Komplicerad<span class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox">Starkare<span class="time">(kan ej beställas)</span></label>
                </div>

                <div class="title">Avicii</div>
                <div class="boxContainer">
                    <label><input type="checkbox">Wake Me Up<span class="time">59 SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox">Hey Brother<span class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox">Waiting For Love<span class="time">(kan ej beställas)</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox">You Make Me<span class="time">29 SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox">Levels<span class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
                </div>

                <div>Välj media:</div>
                <div class="boxContainer">
                    <input type="radio" name = "media"> Spotify
                    <input type="radio" name = "media"> YouTube
                    <input type="radio" name = "media"> Apple Music

                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you.
Just add the function to all your checkboxes.
I added the function to the first 4 checkboxes so that you can see it working.
You should create a global variable called `price` that updates when the function is called.

The price gets updated with the price inside the value everytime a checkbox is clicked.

```js
var price = 0;
function changeContent(boxElement, divToChange, innerDiv) {
    var split     = boxElement.value.split("|");
    var name      = split[0];
    var plusPrice = parseInt(split[1]);
    if(boxElement.checked){
      price = price + plusPrice;
    }
    else{
      price = price - plusPrice;
    }
    
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
    // do something else you need to do
}
```

```css
.boxContainer label{
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="chosenSongs">
    <label>Du har följande skivor:</label>
    <p class = "selectedSongs">Här kommer valda låtar synas</p>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "Polisen"></div>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "Valhalla"></div>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "Raggare på stureplan"></div>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "Monster"></div>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "Instruktionsboken"></div>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "Komplicerad"></div>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "Starkare"></div>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "wake Me Up"></div>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "Hey Brother"></div>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "You Make Me"></div>
    <div class="oneSong" value = "Levels"></div>
</div>

<div class="price">
    <label>Pris:</label>
</div>

<fieldset class="checkbox">
    <div class="title">Ringnes-Ronny</div>
    <div class="boxContainer">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value = "Ringnes-Ronny: Polisen|59"
            onclick = "changeContent(this, 'chosenSongs', 'oneSong')">Polisen<span class="time">59 SEK</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value = "Ringnes-Ronny: Valhalla|39"
            onclick = "changeContent(this, 'chosenSongs', 'oneSong')">Valhalla<span class="time">39 SEK</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value = "Ringnes-Ronny: Raggare på stureplan|49"
            onclick = "changeContent(this, 'chosenSongs', 'oneSong')">Raggare på stureplan<span class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"  value = "Ringnes-Ronny: Monster|39"
            onclick = "changeContent(this, 'chosenSongs', 'oneSong')">Monster<span class="time">39 SEK</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="title">Miss Li</div>
    <div class="boxContainer">
        <label><input type="checkbox">Instruktionsboken<span class="time">39 SEK</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Komplicerad<span class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Starkare<span class="time">(kan ej beställas)</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="title">Avicii</div>
    <div class="boxContainer">
        <label><input type="checkbox">Wake Me Up<span class="time">59 SEK</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Hey Brother<span class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Waiting For Love<span class="time">(kan ej beställas)</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox">You Make Me<span class="time">29 SEK</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Levels<span class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
    </div>

    <div>Välj media:</div>
    <div class="boxContainer">
        <input type="radio" name = "media"> Spotify
        <input type="radio" name = "media"> YouTube
        <input type="radio" name = "media"> Apple Music

    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
Price: <p><c id="price">0</c> SEK</p> 
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works. I've got a another question. How would you be able to make the artist and music also appear and disappear? Is it the same logic as the price?

Comment: Well you should make a list where you append the values of the music to when selecting or remove an item when deselecting. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155230/how-to-add-dynamic-lists-in-javascript-not-jquery

Comment: Mainly the same logic, but you need another method to make the music appear or dissapear.